# how to define a document header of footer for printer in windows printers

Tags: windows, printer

I want to define a document header or footer for all of my print pages on windows.
but I don't know where should define a document template or array.
and one more important thing I don't want to restrict my self to some particular softwares like MS word etc ...

is there any solution regarding that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a workaround but with [Zan Image Printer](http://www.zan1011.com/buy.htm) (a driver to print to image files, price: 59.95$) you could add watermarks (text or bmp - visible) and redirect the result to a true printer.

Perhaps is there other drivers like this but more oriented to header & footer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define a page header or page footer for your printer at the system level, at least not through the operating system.

The only thing I can think of, is if your printer driver offers this support in some way -- that would cause it to print on every page, regardless of application. Have you looked at your printer driver options?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is older than that necklace-holding woman from James Cameron's "Titanic", but I thought I'd share something I just found myself for the benefit of one and all:

There seems to be a system-level print settings similar to the Internet/Proxy settings accessible via Control Panel (and/or Internet Explorer) --

In Internet Explorer, in the gear/settings dropdown, click "Print" -> "Page Setup". In the headers/footers sections below, there are three rows on each side with dropdowns -- each row equates to far-left, middle, and far-right spaces of the header and footer. If you select "Custom" from a dropdown, you're able to add custom text that will be added to all print jobs.

I discovered this only after searching for why everything I print has been having odd custom text injected into the headers/footers, even across printers, even printing to Adobe PDF. I discovered this "system-level" print settings, removed the rogue text (added by a rogue program), and now everything prints just dandy without the text.

Now, both my heart + print headers/footers will go on.